# how to write column one time in csv file in python3

Tags: python, csv, web-crawler, screen-scraping

i am scraping data from news website and save in to title, news and img variable and then write into csv file but i got the repeatation of column name with each scraping row , i want to print only time column name then save my scraping data plz help me 
here is the code

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Zain Noman\Desktop\DN-data.csv', 'a+', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['title','news','img-url'])
    writer.writerows([mylist])
    file.close()
```

[see this output pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b7vj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way

```
file = open('C:\Users\Zain Noman\Desktop\DN-data.csv', 'a+')
writer  = csv.writer(file) #csv wrapper
writer.writerow(['title','news','img-url']) #write the header once
writer.writerows(mylist) #write the the entire list assuming its a list of lists
file.close() #close the file connection
```

Comment: lawrence bro it does not work for  me it add extra space between the letters :(

Comment: can you please show me what your `mylist` look like?
I need to see it before I provide a solution.

Comment: try replacing this line 
`writer.writerows(mylist)`
=>
`writer.writerows([mylist])`

Comment: LAWRENCE bro i also tried this but this wasnt solve my problem .. my list was containing the [title,news,img-url] if u open the picture  link i was giving earlier the question u can see my list

Comment: then you have to go down the list line by line and only print the lines that doesn't have "title" as the first item.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and its simple before the writerow line use this

```
with open('C:Desktop\DN-data.csv', 'a+', newline='') as file:
writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
if file.tell() == 0
  writer.writerow(['title','news','img-url'])
writer.writerows([mylist])
file.close()
```